# I cannot apply custom font in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set a custom font 'warnock' for a body of a card but somehow it applies to none of the tags. However, if I don't include any tags and put the text it sets the font as I set it in css.

```css
.card-body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: warnock, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <p>Microblading is a two step process. After 4 weeks your brows will have healed and we aim to work with a 60% retention rate. This is based upon our products, pigments and skill used in the initial treatment. If you were to leave your brows at this stage
    they would still look ok but you would not see the full benefit of a beautiful pair of brows for the full 12-18months. The initial top up at 4-6 weeks allows me to top up the strokes that need a touch up, bringing the pigment back up to 100%.</p>
  <p>A few more things to consider BEFORE the microblading treatment, if you have any questions about any of it please just shout:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Do not drink coffee, alcohol or energizing drinks on the day of treatment.</li>
    <li> Do not take Aspirin, Niacin, Vitamin E or Ibuprofen 24 hours before treatment.</li>
    <li> Do not take omega3 (fish oil) 1 week before treatment.</li>
    <li> Do not tan or have intense sun exposure 3 days before treatment.</li>
    <li>No waxing 2-3 days before treatment.</li>
    <li> No chemical peels, dermabrasion, laser or any other intense treatments like Botox 2 weeks before or after the treatment.</li>
    <li> Skin should be healthy, non-irritated and blemish free. I cannot blade over spots or Moles.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The text is all white please edit

Comment: please explain your issue

Comment: The problem is not with the color. I have a different background color on my computer so I can see the text clearly. The problem is that font-family is not applying to 'warnock'

Answer (score 0):

fff is white. so you have a white on white and aren't seeing your css take place

```css
.card-body {
  color: green;
  font-family: warnock, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <p>Microblading is a two step process. After 4 weeks your brows will have healed and we aim to work with a 60% retention rate. This is based upon our products, pigments and skill used in the initial treatment. If you were to leave your brows at this stage
    they would still look ok but you would not see the full benefit of a beautiful pair of brows for the full 12-18months. The initial top up at 4-6 weeks allows me to top up the strokes that need a touch up, bringing the pigment back up to 100%.</p>
  <p>A few more things to consider BEFORE the microblading treatment, if you have any questions about any of it please just shout:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Do not drink coffee, alcohol or energizing drinks on the day of treatment.</li>
    <li> Do not take Aspirin, Niacin, Vitamin E or Ibuprofen 24 hours before treatment.</li>
    <li> Do not take omega3 (fish oil) 1 week before treatment.</li>
    <li> Do not tan or have intense sun exposure 3 days before treatment.</li>
    <li>No waxing 2-3 days before treatment.</li>
    <li> No chemical peels, dermabrasion, laser or any other intense treatments like Botox 2 weeks before or after the treatment.</li>
    <li> Skin should be healthy, non-irritated and blemish free. I cannot blade over spots or Moles.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is not with the color. I have a different background color on my computer so I can see the text clearly. The problem is that font-family is not applying to 'warnock'

Comment: Do you have that font installed?

Comment: I do! http://skuskastudio.000webhostapp.com/beauty.html Here if you scroll down to the FAQ section and see the carousel, you can see that is works in the second and third but in the first box it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `color: #fff` to `color: black`.